# how to preserve the line break in input parameter of a vba function return it properly?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to develop a VBA function in excel for parsing a string.
Here is my function:

```
Function parseTemplate(template As String) As String
     parseTemplate = template
End Function
```

Suppose I enter the following value into cell "c1":

```
I
am
Boy
```

I parse the formula `=parseTemplate(c1)` in d1 cell,
and I expect the result is:

```
I
am
Boy
```

However, the actual result is:

```
Iamboy
```

So, how to ensure the output string can preserve the line break in the input parameter?

Comment: What you show us is not a real string... In VBA a string must be enclosed between double quotes. If you do not take it form somewhere else. Where from does your function take it? Is it in an Excel cell and you split the words in the way you show us? Please, better explain this part of your question.

Comment: Use `Chr(10)` then format the result cell `Wrap Text`.

Comment: @Harun24HR How to use Chr(10) if the string itself does not have any end of line? Where to place it? The string **only looks like having** tree lines. He should explain where from this string has been taken, in order to find a way to process it as he needs, I think... Am I missing something?

Comment: You did not clarify the main issue: **Where from you take the string to be processed**? If difficult to explain, please place a picture with it... Does the string really have two end of lines?

Comment: The string is taken from cell c1 value.

Comment: **How did you obtain the three lines** you show us? Did you press `Alt + Enter` after each line, or only set Wrap text and played with the column width?

Comment: Yes, I press `Alt + Enter` after each line.

Comment: Then you only must check the `Wrap Text` property  = `True`

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you, I set the cell d1 Wrap Text = true, it works.

Comment: You must know that a UDF function **can only change the value**! It cannot change format... You can use any Sub to automate it in VBA. This line works in any sub: `ActiveCell.WrapText = True`